# Versioning solution for Tumblr themes

Tags: versioning, tumblr, tumblr-themes

My question concerns a situation in which 2 or more people are working on the same Tumblr theme at the same time.
So, has anyone come across a nice/hacky/dirty programmatic solution that would make it possible without having to move outside of Tumblr?
Alternatively, moving outside of Tumblr but without gong to lengths of using Github?

I will be extremely grateful for any advice on that.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. If you need versioning, you need version control, ala Git / SVN.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mikedidthis. Good to have it clarified - I was after an 'intermediate' versioning solution, not as robust as Git and hopefully  [somehow] pluggable into Tumblr (maybe via API)... If you don't know it this is ok, maybe someone else does.